# ideavim - command mode tab and save directory

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I'm happily using ideavim and getting great results so far.

One question -- I am trying to save a copy of my file using :w  . I can't find where IJ has saved the file. When I try and tab-complete the current directory, the tab operation is handled by the top breadcrumb navigator and pulls me out of the editor.

Two questions then:

1. what directory does ideavim :w save a new file in? I saved a 'foobar.java' and I can't find it in my source tree.
2. How do I get IJ to stop intercepting the tab key and let vim command mode do a directory name autocompletion?

Thanks !

ps. Here's a screencast of the problem -->

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xwwv54w5cbt81rb/ideavim-480p.mov?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:w` command only saves the current file, you cannot supply a path to cause it to write to a different file.

There's an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-989) against IDEA VIM for this.

Also, there are some open issues relating to focus switching to the navbar when using the `:w` command:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1009
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1015